# How to make a case insensitive query in Azure Digital Twins

Tags: azure, azure-digital-twins

So I have this code in C# that performs a query in DT

```
query = digitalTwinsClientInstance.QueryAsync<BasicDigitalTwin>(
                @$"SELECT Child, Child.$metadata.$model
                FROM DIGITALTWINS
                    ...
                WHERE Area.$dtId = '{areaId}'

                  AND CONTAINS(Child.Name, '{textFilter}')"
            );
```

However, I would like for the search to be **case insensitive.** Is there any way to do that in the query itself, since Azure DT **dos not** support UPPER or LOWER functions?

This is the functionality that I would like

```
query = digitalTwinsClientInstance.QueryAsync<BasicDigitalTwin>(
                @$"SELECT Child, Child.$metadata.$model
                FROM DIGITALTWINS
                    ...
                WHERE Area.$dtId = '{areaId}'

                  AND CONTAINS(LOWER(Child.Name), '{textFilter.ToLower()}')" // !! Does Not Work
            );
```

Comment: hope this helps [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/digital-twins/how-to-manage-twin)

Comment: @Sampath that page doesn't address any of the posters issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. There is native support for case-insensitive queries in ADT.

A possible workaround is to store a second property on your twin, with the same data but lowercase. Not ideal, but it works.

Comment: Thank you! Do you mean “No native support?”

Comment: Oh sorry, I meant it's just not supported. There is no function for this in the query language. There's only workarounds 